# Failure running sonar-runner locally

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have an instance of sonar running on my local machine at localhost:9000, and I'm able to go to and use the console. When I try to run sonar-runner from the command line for a project, I get a 500 error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.DatabaseCompatibility.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.DatabaseCompatibility@3848110b, org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/api/server]. Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: org.picocontainer.PicoLifecycleException: PicoLifecycleException: method 'public void org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.DatabaseCompatibility.start()', instance 'org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.DatabaseCompatibility@3848110b, org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://localhost:9000/api/server]. Response code: 500
    at org.picocontainer.monitors.NullComponentMonitor.lifecycleInvocationFailed(NullComponentMonitor.java:77)
...
...
```

But when i visit the url in my browser, I get the following xml response:

```
<server>
<id>20131007131041</id>
<version>3.4.1</version>
<status>UP</status>
</server>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: Do you confirm that your database settings are the same in SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties and SONARQUBE_RUNNER_HOME/conf/sonar-runner.properties ?

Answer (score 4):

The current workaround is to unset `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` variables before launching the sonar webservice:

```
unset GEM_PATH GEM_HOME
./sonar.sh console
```

This doesn't have to be done for the sonar-runner environment.

The problem is caused due to [conflict with Ruby local installation](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3579).

Comment: You could probably add in how to use the same instead of simply linking it in.

Comment: link only answers are typically frowned upon because links do die over time.  it is beneficial, for everyone, to include a summary of the important bits here.

Answer (score 1):

As per the sonar-runner documentation you need to create a `sonar-project.properties` in your project root and then run `sonar-runner` from command line

ref [Sonar runner docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)

In my case it worked with following workaround

1: `export GEM_HOME=''`

2: `export GEM_PATH=''`

3: restart sonar webserver

4: run `sonar-runner` in project path